# JSON PHP foreach empty value

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm working with PHP and JSON. I have this example of a JSON foreach loop, with this example I want to get lat/lon to add a marker in Google Maps:

```
"data": [
       {
          "end_time": "2016-02-09T22:30:00-0200",
          "name": "6\u00ba Rebanh\u00e3o de Carnaval - Comunidade Cen\u00e1culo",
          "place": {
             "name": "Comunidade Cen\u00e1culo",
             "location": {
                "city": "Franca",
                "country": "Brazil",
                "latitude": "",
                "longitude": "",
                "state": "SP",
                "street": "Dom Pedro I, 1040, Jardim Petr\u00e1glia"
             },
             "id": "410657548946610"
          },
          "start_time": "2016-02-05T19:30:00-0200",
          "id": "940527599373114"
       }
    ]
```

My problem is, some of results of latitude and longitude are empty. I want to put a specific value on it, but on each empty I want to add lat + 0.02.

For example, in first empty value I want to put this lat 40.700106, and the next empty value I want to put this 40.700106 + 0.02.

I just don't want 2 markers in same location.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

```
foreach($json3 ->data as $mydata1)
{
$latitude = $mydata1->place->location->latitude;
if(empty($latitude ))
    {

        $latitude = $latitude + 0.02;
        echo ' lat :'.$latitude ;
    }
}
```

this way i replace the empty value, but they dont add the + 0.02 on each value

Comment: Where is your code? What is the issue you are facing with your first attempt at tackling the problem?

Comment: i Edited my code.

Comment: @reemy to modify the `$json3` you need to reference in foreach... `foreach ($json3->data as &$mydata1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the previous latitude and use it.

Something like this:

```
$previousLatitude = null;
foreach($json3 ->data as $mydata1) {
    $latitude = $mydata1->place->location->latitude;
    if(empty($latitude ))
    {
        $latitude = $previousLatitude + 0.02;
        echo ' lat :'.$latitude ;
    }

    $previousLatitude = $latitude
}
```

Comment: thx man...i just modified a little, but i get the logic by your answer, and it worked